# Code generation in java bean with for each loop

Tags: java

This is my function which return null always.. But i want the output as `RECY0` for the first time and then second time `RECY1` an so on...

```
public String generateRecycleCode()  {      
   Integer recycleNoIncremnt=0;
   String code= null;   
   for(MaterialRecycleIssueBean materialRecycleIssueBean : materialRecycleIssueBeanlist){
       materialRecycleIssueBean.recyleCode = "RECY"+recycleNoIncremnt++;
       code = materialRecycleIssueBean.recyleCode;      
   }
   return code;
}
```

Comment: `materialRecycleIssueBeanlist` is most likely empty.